# Creating Login form in Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

Got an academic task at school and I've been stuck for a week now.
I'm supposed to create a loginform in Windows form application by using Streamreader/-writer. Username and password have to be stored locally in projekt in a .txt-file, and I'm suppose to use a class for login.
Question is how to set this up. What methods do I use in class login and do I use a second class for Streamreader/-writer? Where and how do I enter username and password since it have to be encrypted in .txt-file.
I've had an idea as follow

```
 class Login1
{
    public string userName = "USER";
    public string passWord = "PASS";
    public int mainKey = 68;

    string userNameFileText;
    string passWordFileText;

    public static string Encrypt(string t, int n)
    {
        char ch;
        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i <= t.Length -1 ; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(t.Substring(i, 1));
            ch = (char)(ch + n);
            temp += ch;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public void  WriteToFileUserName()
    {
        //string text = userName;
        //int key = mainKey;
        string enCryptedUserNameText;

        enCryptedUserNameText = Encrypt(userName, mainKey);

        StreamWriter userNameWriteFile = new StreamWriter("username.txt");
        userNameWriteFile.WriteLine(enCryptedUserNameText);
    }

    public void WriteToFilePassWord()
    {
        string text = passWord;
        int key = mainKey;
        string enCryptedPassWordText;

        enCryptedPassWordText = Encrypt(passWord, mainKey);

        StreamWriter passWordWriteFile = new StreamWriter("password.txt");
        passWordWriteFile.WriteLine(enCryptedPassWordText);
    }

    public void DeCryptUserName()
    {

        string deCryptedUserName;

        StreamReader userNameReadFile = new StreamReader("username.txt");

        while (!userNameReadFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            userNameFileText = userNameReadFile.ReadLine();
        }
        userNameReadFile.Close();

        deCryptedUserName = Login1.Encrypt(userNameFileText, -mainKey);
    }

    private void DeCryptPassWord()
    {
        string deCryptedPassWord;

        StreamReader passWordReadFile = new StreamReader("password.txt");

        while (!passWordReadFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            passWordFileText = passWordReadFile.ReadLine();
        }
        passWordReadFile.Close();

        deCryptedPassWord = Login1.Encrypt(passWordFileText, -mainKey);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have 2 `TextBox` for `UserName` and `Password` and 2 `Buttons` for `SignUp` and `SignIn`. You can implement logic of registration and signing in in the following way:

```
Usings:

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Forms code:

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _filePath = @"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\logins.txt";
    private int encryptNumber = 32;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string Encrypt(string value)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        char[] arr = value.ToCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i< arr.Length;i++)
        {
            result += (char)(arr[i] + encryptNumber);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private string Decrypt(string value)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        char[] arr = value.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            result +=(char)(arr[i] - encryptNumber);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void SignUpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginTxtBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passTxtBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login/password");
            return;
        }
        if (CheckLogPass(_filePath))
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login/password");
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(_filePath, "\r\n" + Encrypt(loginTxtBox.Text + "|" + passTxtBox.Text));
            MessageBox.Show("Successful SignUp, now you can SignIn");
        }
    }

    private void SignInBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginTxtBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passTxtBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login/password");
            return;
        }
        if(CheckLogPass(_filePath))
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully SignIn");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login/password");
    }

    private bool CheckLogPass(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_filePath))
        {
            File.Create(_filePath);
        }
        using (var fs = File.OpenText(_filePath))
        {
            while (!fs.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = fs.ReadLine();
                string decrypted = Decrypt(line);
                if (decrypted.Contains(loginTxtBox.Text + "|" + passTxtBox.Text))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You don't need to take File Write/Read part to separate class if you won't add another forms which will also use them.

Comment: Thx for help but I'm not sure I understand SignUp versus SignIn? I do have two textboxes for UserName and PassWord and two buttons for Exit and Login. I also dont see where I set username and password? I'm sorry but I am quite new to this but I really appreciate the examples and all help.

Comment: @Tarbh SignUp is used for registering user, while sign in is users authorization it's same log in

Comment: The thought is that when u login successfully, the "main"-form opens up for the Membersite (I'll figure out how that work next) and the login-form closes.

Comment: @Tarbh ok, so if I don't have username and password I need first to register my self which is doing SignUp and it will write my login and pass to file after that I can log in/ sign in with sign in button which will check provided data to exists in file and if it exists let me pass

Comment: Ok, basically it means that anyone can signup and then sign in. I was more after a solution that a newly member gets a username and password to use for entering (login) on members page. Maybe I don't get u but the way I understand it u first sign up by entering a username and password by choice (that gets saved in .txt-file) after that u can sign in??!

Comment: @Tarbh Yes , you understood correctly

Comment: Is there a way to use your system (cause I like it) by not letting anyone sign up but for example me so I alone can create username and password for user and then they get it by mail for example. Lets say i use it as it is but its a "hidden" button to sign in...don't laugh :)

Comment: @Tarbh You can ask for special password besides the login and password while sign up so that nobody will be able to sign up without knowing that password and send login password  to user with SMTP client

Comment: Like a simple textbox that compares to a string in code basically??

Comment: @Tarbh yeah, something like that

Comment: Thats an idea, even if I don't like writing passwords in code but the task is like a catch 22 :) Thx for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to make another class for using stream writer, sounds to me like they wanted you to show you can separate logic from GUI, which makes the code reusable. For example if you created a mobile app you could reuse your login class with no need to rewrite the code. What you have so far seems to be on the right track. Any additional login logic needs to be kept of of the GUI.